# Why does this loop repeat itself twice? It looks through certain term belonging to a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I want to loop through a specific term for a custom_taxonomy, and displays the posts that belong to that specific term. My code is repeating itself twice at the moment, I don't know why:

```
<?php
get_header();
//for a given post type, return all
?>

<?php 
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
$storyterm =  $term->name;
?>
  <?php 

  $post_type = 'event';
  $tax =  'event-categories '; 
  $tax_terms = get_terms($tax);
  if ($tax_terms) {
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
      $args=array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'event-categories' =>  $storyterm,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'caller_get_posts'=> 1
      ); // END $args

      $my_query = null;
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo 'List of '.$post_type . ' where the taxonomy <em>'. $tax . '</em>  is <strong>'. $tax_term->name .'</strong>';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
          <?php
        endwhile;
      } // END if have_posts loop
      wp_reset_query();
    } // END foreach $tax_terms
  } // END if $tax_terms

get_footer();
```

**What I am trying to achieve:** I want to loop through a  specific term for a custom_taxonomy, and displays the posts that belong to that specific term

Comment: How many elements are in $tax_terms? Why don't you print_r($tax_terms) and find out? Sounds like there might be 2.

Comment: @JackAlbright I get `WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid taxonomy ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) ) List of event where the taxonomy event-categories is` when I `print_r($tax_terms);` I'm not sure what this means